# Learning Curve to Know Underfitting or Overfitting

Tags: random-forest, svm, overfitting

I want to know if the model I am using tends to be overfitting or underfitting. I am using SVM and Random Forest algorithms. How to figure it out?
[image: Random Forest] [image: SVM]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest plotting your observed versus predicted values as a first indication of whether your model may be overfitting or underfitting. The plots at https://bookdown.org/gmli64/do_a_data_science_project_in_10_days/models-underfitting-and-overfitting.html show good visual examples of overfitting and underfitting. An indication of overfitting is if your performance metrics are better for the training data than the test data. High bias and low variance can indicate underfitting.